# Creating an associative array from a csv file php

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to read a csv file and then store the first and the 21st column in an associative array such that the 1st column becomes the key and 21st column becomes the value.

Later I would want to pull records based on the "key". The PHP file containing the code is upload.php

```
$calls = array();
$file_handle = fopen($C1.".File.csv","r"); // $C1 is defined before.
 //Just appending something to the file name. This file exists. 
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line= fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $calls[$line[0]] = $line[20]; //Line 94 of this file

}
fclose($file_handle);
print_r($calls);
```

I get this error

```
Undefined offset: 20 in upload.php on line 94
```

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: What is in upload.php on line 94? Because you don't use offset 24 anywhere here so your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: You're missing a comma in that row. Or it's possible the entire line is blank. var_dump($line);

Comment: Sorry offset 20 in this case.. Not 24

Comment: Consider using `fgetcsv()` function

manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The twentieth "column" in a zero-indexed array would be `$line[19]`

update as per your comment (and subsequent edit):

The error is clearly pointing out at some point during the loop `$line[20]` is not set - If each line has a suitable number of columns then the only other reason I can think of is that there is an empty line at the end of the CSV file.

Eg.

```
1.  foo, bar, baz
2.  a  , b  , c
3.                    <-- empty line as a result of carriage return
```

so... you want to check that `trim($line)!=''` before `fgetcsv` and/or as part of good error-handling check that the array's length is greater than the highest index you are trying to read.

Comment: Thanks.but I don't think thats the error. The csv that I'm trying to read has around 50 columns.